# How to "overload" dollar operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, dollar-sign

First of all, sorry if this question was already asked, I simply couldn't find the proper english terms to express what I meant.

I was wondering if there was any Type Class in Haskell representing function application in order to define multiple behavior for different data types.

Using the `Graphics.X11.Xlib` package, I came across lots of different functions asking for the exact same parameters. So my idea was to pack these functions into a tuple (because their return type is not the same), and feed them all at once the parameters. Like so:

```hs
import Graphics.X11.Xlib

main = do
  display <- openDisplay ":0"
  let dScreen = defaultScreen display
      (black, white, cMap) =
      -- here is where the "parameter dispatch" is needed
      (blackPixel, whitePixel, defaultColormap)  display dScreen

  -- computation
  return ()
```

I didn't find anything, so I decided to create this kind of Type Class:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Graphics.X11.Xlib

class Dispatch f x y | x y -> f where
  dsp :: f -> x -> y
instance Dispatch (a -> b, a -> c, a -> d) a (b, c, d) where
  dsp (f, g, h) x = (f x, g x, h x)

main = do
  display <- openDisplay ":0"
  let dScreen = defaultScreen display
      (black, white, cMap) =
      -- here is where the "parameter dispatch" is needed
      (blackPixel, whitePixel, defaultColormap) `dsp` display `dsp` dScreen

  -- computation
  return ()
```

It works fine, and by multiplying instances for different tuple sizes, one can simply add or remove functions from the "function tuple" depending on the needed values, and the code will still compile.

But is there any way to do it without this workaround ?
I tried using `Control.Applicative` or `Control.Arrow` but multiple parameter functions don't end up well.

My best attempt so far is: `(,) <$> blackPixel <*> whitePixel`

Comment: Have you looked at `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)`

Comment: Oh, this would be nice, but how do you apply `uncurry` to every functions in the tuple ? Composing `uncurry` N times is not really a solution, as we still need to copy the same code for each function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xlib, so maybe somebody else can comment what's the canonical way to work with it. But your `dsp` function would work just fine as a normal helper function somewhere (like `curry` and `uncurry`) – you don't need a typeclass for that. Maybe see http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions

Comment: I like that class you propose, though I find it surprising that you would make the fundep `x y -> f` instead of `f x -> y`, or even `f -> x, f -> y`.

Comment: @mb21 What you propose would make me create as many `dspX` functions as there are tuple sizes ^^ @leftaroundabout I am totaly new to fundep, and I don't really know how to decide which fundep to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but here's how you could extend this idea to a true “overloading of the `$` operator”:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Prelude hiding (($))

infixr 0 $

class Dispatch f where
  type Argument f :: *
  type Result f :: *
  ($) :: f -> Argument f -> Result f

instance Dispatch (a -> b) where
  type Argument (a->b) = a
  type Result (a->b) = b
  f $ x = f x

instance (Dispatch x, Dispatch y, Argument x ~ Argument y)
            => Dispatch (x,y) where
  type Argument (x,y) = Argument x
  type Result (x,y) = (Result x, Result y)
  (f,g) $ a = (f $ a, g $ a)

instance ( Dispatch x, Dispatch y, Dispatch z
         , Argument x ~ Argument y, Argument y ~ Argument z )
            => Dispatch (x,y,z) where
  type Argument (x,y,z) = Argument x
  type Result (x,y,z) = (Result x, Result y, Result z)
  (f,g,h) $ a = (f $ a, g $ a, h $ a)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   print $ ((\x -> ((2*x+),(3*x+)), (**), logBase) $ 2) $ 4
```

```
((8.0,10.0),16.0,2.0)
```

Comment: This is so much more powerful than my typeclass ! And teached me how to use ̀type` in classes. Thank you. So short answer : no way to do it dynamically, we will always have to either define N functions for N-uple, or create a typeclass and instantiate it N times.

Comment: @Shumush yeah, but since you can nest tuples (my class handles those fine) you don't really need _N_ times, you basically just need pair and perhaps add triples and quadruples for convenience and a bit better performance, and build up anything bigger from those.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply many functions to a single argument with the `liftA` family of functions. Nest them to apply many functions to many arguments. So:

```
(b, w, m) = liftA3 (liftA3 (,,)) blackPixel whitePixel defaultColormap display dScreen
```

Comment: So we would need as many `liftA3` as there are parameters ? And there is no other way to change the number of functions in the tuple without another functino like `liftA4` ... `liftAN`

Comment: @Shumush If you take a look at how the `liftA` family is defined you will see that of course there is another way. =)